# Power BI- Create Radio Button Filter (Right Side Pane, not on the Dashboard/Worksheet)

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I've a right side pane filter at the page level with checkbox selection option (see yellow highlighted filter). I want to make change it as a radio button in the right pane not on the worksheet.

[image]

The radio button filter should look like this:-

[image]

Any suggestion/help would be appreciated....

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Put all those (Applied Intelligence, Automotive, Banking) into ONE COLUMN

Comment: You are limited to the style on the filter pane, for radio style, you will need to use the filter visual